# Why do we need both (void)viewDidUnload and (void)dealloc {

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dealloc

When is a view unloaded and yet not deallocated?

Why do in viewDidUnload we do

self.member = nil;

and in dealloc we do

[member release]

They do almost the same thing but why we do one in viewDidUnload and the other in dealloc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewDidUnload get called when your app receive a memory warning.
You have to release all retained views that can be reconstructed in loadView or viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be doing that, as member will be `nil` when you send the `release` message in your `dealloc` method, so the original `member` will leak.

Comment: Was this modded down for any particular reason?

Comment: because there is no leak when you use the synthesized setter. The setter will release the old object before assigning a new one.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidUnload is called when the view is unloaded (hence the name) and is used to unload basically everything you load with loadView oder viewDidLoad to free up memory when memory resources are scarse. The system gives you an opportunity to free up resources that can later be loaded again with viewDidLoad / loadView. Usually, you would free up every visual components or hierarchies you created in viewDidLoad or over the NIB. But you would retain your data and free only resources that cannot get automatically (viewidLoad, loadView or any of your own caching mechanisms) reloaded. 
In dealloc you release everything that is retained by your class